# Show "!" label when the date is close

Tags: qgis, date

In the attribute table I have a column "the end of the contract" with date. I want QGIS to show me the label "!" when there will be 30 days or less until the end of the contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Would like to expand on Ian's answer and the comment you made:

You have to convert the `now()` also into a date because `now()` also holds the current time. This will yield an `interval`. So you convert it into `day` and get an integer value which can be compared.

The final query looks like this:

```
if( day( to_date( '2019-02-26') - to_date(now()))  <30, '!', 'Some other Label')
```

The date in here can be any field which holds a valid date

---

Edit: 
For labeling you should try:

```
day( to_date( '2019-02-26') - to_date(now()))  <30
```

and as label insert your '!' as in this screenshot

[image]

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: @MonikaMarczuk whats the error message you receive?

Comment: there's no error, it doesn't show anything on the map, the code works in the attribute table, it colors the field in red when the date is close

Comment: glad I could help :)

Comment: @MonikaMarczuk sorry I dont understand your question. are you talking about the labels? maybe post it as a new question and explain your issue in detail

Comment: what will be the code to show "!!" when the end date is less than 60 days but longer than 30? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression to control when a label is shown, so in this case you could use something like

```
DateCol -  Now() < 30
```

To turn on a ! label.

Comment: thanks, but doesn't work, show me "The conversion "2019-02-26" to double failed"

Comment: You probably need to wrap your column in a date parser.

Comment: doesn't work :(